# Coffeescript and node-supervisor together?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm using coffeescript with --watch option to rebuild javascript on changes to .coffee files.

Is it safe to combine that with node-supervisor to restart Node on changes to the compiled javascript?

I'm worried it won't be robust because of atomicity when coffeescript is recompiling multiple files.  node-supervisor could jump the gun and restart Node on detecting the first filesystem change.  Is it robust enough to realize there were additional changes while it was busy restarting Node?

Is there a better way?  Ideally I'd have only one filesystem watcher recompile my coffeescript and restart node.

Comment: How do you watch coffee files recursively? perhaps you could give me ahand with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470334/autocompile-coffee-files-and-reload-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use nodemon, it even has a delay feature (to restart server after a number of seconds have passed), for example:

```
nodemon --debug ./server.coffee 80
```

Another good feature of [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) is ignoring files, example:

```
# this is my ignore file with a nice comment at the top

/vendor/*     # ignore all external submodules
/public/*     # static files
./README.md   # a specific file
*.css         # ignore any CSS files too
```

Other than that, read the documentation on the [github repo](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and watch this Nodetuts video about nodemon: http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/14-some-nodejs-tools.html

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the delay function.   I'll play around with this.

Comment: Note that by default nodemon ignores .coffee files exceptiong specified app file.
So if you don't precompile your .coffee files, you will have a problem.
I solved it by adding .nodemonignore file to project root, it rewrites default rules and nodemon started to watch all required .coffee files

Comment: I had to prepend --nodejs before --debug to get this to work with coffeescript: nodemon --nodejs --debug ./server.coffee

Answer (score 7):

Create a JavaScript launcher, i.e. `run.js`, like this:

```
require('coffee-script');
require('./launch');
```

Then run this file with supervisor and appropriate options:

```
supervisor -e "node|js|coffee" run.js
```

This worked well for me on Windows.

Comment: No need to create separate js file. You can specify executable with `-x` option. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18373394/93988).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`supervisor`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) with `-x` option set to `coffee`. This will enable it to run script with right executable:

```
supervisor -x coffee your-script.coffee
```

Inspired by [Lemming's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216056/93988).

Answer (score 1):

In some of my Cakefiles, such as the one for [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets/blob/master/Cakefile), I do the watching myself and simply spawn `coffee -co lib src` each time something changes, then restart the server when that child process finishes. That gets around the atomicity issue. If every `.coffee` file changes at once (or if you upgrade the `coffee` runtime), all of the JS files will update at once as well.

Comment: Nice!  I don't even fully understand your cakefile yet.  But that looks like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My foreman centric solution looks like this:

`Procfile.dev`

```
web: ./node_modules/supervisor/lib/cli-wrapper.js -n exit server.js
watch: ./node_modules/iced-coffee-script/bin/coffee --watch --compile server.iced
```

and then merely `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`

Then `gitignore` the resulting `.js` files. I like this approach because it keeps a constantly-updating vanilla JS file alongside my `.iced` files, so I can doublecheck my work as I go (I definitely make mistakes in coffeescript that I might not in vanilla).

Comment: this is great, but I cannot seem to run node-supervisor with `--debug`