# autocompile .coffee files and reload project

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node-modules

I have a small web service developed in node, and I'd like to code some files in coffeescript, to start playing with it.

I'm using nodemon to run the app, like this

```
nodemon app.js
```

And I have the following file structure

app.js
controllers/
  ping.coffee
  test.js

In [nodemon's homepage](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#readme) it says that it supports coffeescript, but I change the file and it won't get reloaded.

Then I found [this article](http://glennstovall.com/blog/2012/05/07/rapid-development-with-node-dot-js-and-coffeescript/), so I tried with

```
$ coffee --watch --compile ./controllers/*.coffee
```

And it works fine, but if I try with

```
$ coffee --watch --compile ./*.coffee 
File not found: ./*.coffee
```

So it seems like the watch option is not recursive.

Any idea how can I make nodemon pick coffeescript files changes, or have the coffee compiler pick files recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
coffee --watch --compile ./
```

Also, you can shorten the flags to `-wc`.

Answer (score 3):

Nodemon will properly watch the coffeescript files if you explicitly specify their extension with `-e js,coffee`. This is counter to what the docs state and I've filed a ticket on this issue here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/312

Comment: run with `$nodemon app.js -e coffee`

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is pretty common in coffeescript libraries. Many libraries have a script to compile all coffeescript files in one directory to Javascript files in another. For example, the following `Cakefile` compiles from `src/` to `lib/`. You can `cake watch` or `cake build` depending on what you want to do.

```
{print} = require 'util'
{spawn} = require 'child_process'

task 'build', 'Build lib/ from src/', ->
  coffee = spawn 'coffee', ['-c', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
  coffee.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stderr.write data.toString()
  coffee.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    print data.toString()
  coffee.on 'exit', (code) ->
    callback?() if code is 0

task 'watch', 'Watch src/ for changes', ->
  coffee_src = spawn 'coffee', ['-w', '-c', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
  coffee_src.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> process.stderr.write data.toString()
  coffee_src.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
```

However, if you're not running node but actually running a browser app, I would suggest using the fantastic [hem](https://github.com/spine/hem). For that, I've also written a getting-started guide on here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993583/586086